# How to change order of integration for this integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question is to write the following integral with respect to polar coordinates one time where we integrate $drd\theta$ and then another one were it is $d\theta dr$.

$$\int_0^1\int_0^x~f(x,y)~dydx$$

By sketching the region I have managed to figure out the first part I get this as $$\int_0^{\pi /4}\int_0^{\csc {\theta}}~f(r,\theta)~rdrd\theta$$  which I think is correct.

Now for the second part I'm struggling to determine the coordinates for $\theta$. I have $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt 2$ but then for any such $r$ we just have a straight line i.e $\theta$ is a constant which makes me think I am wrong?

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have two subsets:
$$0\le r\le 1\implies 0\le\theta\le\pi/4,$$
$$1\le r\le\sqrt2\implies \arccos(1/r)\le\theta\le\pi/4.$$

Comment: Can you explain how to deduce this? I don't understand how my answer to the first part is wrong I will upload my working please advise.

Comment: http://imgur.com/n2qiGbA How is this wrong? Could you please explain how you work out your limits please.

Comment: For each $r\le 1$, the point moves between the $X$ axis and the line $y = x$. For each $r\ge 1$, the point moves between the lines $x = 1$ and $y = x$.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand, are we just talking about the second case now or the first one or both?

Comment: @Remi, both cases. I will add an image later.

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting there... Shouldn't it be $\arcsin (1/r)$ for the second line though?

Comment: @Remi, $1 = x = r\cos\theta$.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad I was thinking the line was $y=1$ not $x=1$